# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a simple login validation, but I'm getting this error when I deliberately input an incorrect email in the login post method via postman.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null at C:\Users\layug\Documents\work\zuitt\batch-125\s32 -36\course-booking-api\controllers\userControllers.js:54:74 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

When the email is correct, and the password is wrong, I can get the *wrong email or password message* error message.

The problem is when the email is incorrect, or the email isn't found in the database (through the 'result' variable). In these cases, it starts showing the error in the console.

The code I am using is the following.

```js
module.exports.login = (reqBody) => {
  // model method
  return User.findOne({email: reqBody.email}).then((result, error) => {
    // This is the line causing the error.
    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(reqBody.password, result.password);
    if (result == null || isPasswordCorrect == false) {
      return "Email or password is incorrect";
    } else {
      return {access: auth.createAccessToken(result.toObject())};
    }
  });
}
```

When I write my conditions like this, everything works fine, but this is not my ideal condition for my login validation.

```js
module.exports.login = (reqBody) => {
  return User.findOne({ email: reqBody.email }).then((result, error) => {
    if (result == null) {
      return "Email not registered";
    } else {
      const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(reqBody.password, result.password);
      if (isPasswordCorrect === true) {
        return { access: auth.createAccessToken(result.toObject()) };
      } else {
        return "Wrong password";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What did you pass to the `login` function?

Comment: This could be because of the accessing `reqBody.password` where `password` property in the request body is null.
Try if you can use Optional Chaining (ES2020) in your code where this would be `reqBody?.password`. If not, check the password property if its null explicitly.

Comment: @PyxlDavon just a request.body data, containing the email and password

Comment: Can you post the HTML form as the body comes from there

Comment: @HadidAli, I'm not sure with optional chainring, never heard of it. I'm sure though the password is not being null since I can login if both email and password are correct or shows incorrect email or password if only the password is incorrect

Comment: @PyxlDavon, is just a form through postman , I pass the login information as JSON object like this       "email": "ana@sophias.com",
  "password":  "12345678901"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix is to wrap your function that tries to get user password in a try-catch statement. In this case you are looking up a user that does not exist, which returns a null, which you then try read the password of, giving you the error 'cannot read password of null'

```
//model method
return User.findOne({ email: reqBody.email }).then((result, error) => {
  //below is the line where I get the error
  try {
    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(
      reqBody.password,
      result.password
    );

    if (result == null || isPasswordCorrect == false) {
      return "Email or password is incorrect";
    } else {
      return { access: auth.createAccessToken(result.toObject()) };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return "Email does not exist";
  }
});
```

Your solution is fine btw.

Comment: Well to put it simply, you look for an email on your database. The email does not exist on the database, so it returns 'null'. After which you try and read 'password' from the 'null' value, which prompts node to throw an error. The try catch attempts to find the password value on the returned 'null' value, but when the error is thrown, instead of crashing your app, it is caught by the catch statement, you then return the "Email not found".

Comment: hello. thanks for your output. However, 'email does not exist' is the one I want to exclude. Simply I just need to display "incorrect email or password" when either one is wrong. I tried your solution since I'm still new to try catch and like to see how it works.

Comment: @oh kr4bz, my bad I didn't realized that. facepalm. Sorry guys and thank you